# D3.js onclick switching other line color

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

can you help me why this is not working properly?

This is a physics demo, and the concept is that i can change the color of the line if i click on it, and when i click on a rectangle i want to change all of the sides (line around it) color, and always change to the other color. So the line is white or red, and only the line color change, and i can click on the line or rectangle. This code nearly works good.

Two problem left:

1. if click on the rectangle the sides change the color to red, but not back,
2. if before 1 line was red it not change to white

I hope i was clear, here is where i am stuck:

```js
// grid basic variables
var dimension = 10,
 width = 50,
 height = 50;

function gridData() {
 var data = new Array();

 // rectangle variables
 var rectXpos = 0,
   rectYpos = 0,
   rectWidth = width,
   rectHeight = height;
  click = 0;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension; column++) {
   // rectClass = "rect" + rectXpos.toString() + rectYpos.toString();
   data.push({
    x: rectXpos,
    y: rectYpos,
    width: rectWidth,
    height: rectHeight,
    // class: rectClass,
    click: click
   });

   // increment the x position. I.e. move it over by 50 (width variable)
   rectXpos += rectWidth;
  }
  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  rectXpos = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  rectYpos += rectHeight;
 }
 return data;
}

var gridData = gridData();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(gridData);

var grid = d3.select("#grid")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width*dimension)
 .attr("height",height*dimension);

var rect = grid.selectAll(".square")
 .data(gridData)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("class","rect")
 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
 .style("fill", "#f2f2f2")
 .style("stroke", "#fff")
 .on("click", function(d){
  d.click ++;
  var nextColor = (this.style.stroke == "red") ? "white" : "red";
  d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString()).style("stroke", nextColor);
  d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", nextColor);
  d3.select(".hline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", nextColor);
  d3.select(".hline" + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", nextColor);
 });

function hlinegriddata() {
 var data = new Array();

 // line variables
 var hlineX1 = 0,
   hlineY1 = 0,
   hlineX2 = 0,
   hlineY2 = 50,
  click = 0;

 var lineLength = width;

 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension + 1; column++) {
   hlineClass = "hline" + hlineX1.toString() + hlineY1.toString() + hlineX2.toString() + hlineY2.toString();
   data.push({
    x1: hlineX1,
    y1: hlineY1,
    x2: hlineX2,
    y2: hlineY2,
    class: hlineClass,
    click: click
   });

        // increment the x position for the next line
        hlineX1 += lineLength;
        hlineX2 += lineLength;
  }

  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  hlineX1 = 0;
  hlineX2 = 0;

  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  hlineY1 += lineLength;
  hlineY2 += lineLength;
 }
 return data;
}

var hlinegriddata = hlinegriddata();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(hlinegriddata);

var hline = grid.selectAll(".hline")
 .data(hlinegriddata)
 .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })
 .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
 .style("stroke", "white")
 .style("stroke-width", "4")
 .style("cursor", "pointer")
 .on("click", function(){var nextColor = this.style.stroke == "white" ? "red" : "white";
            d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
 });
 // .on('click', function(d) {
 //  d.click ++;
    //    if ((d.click)%2 == 0 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#fff"); }
 //    if ((d.click)%2 == 1 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","red"); }
    // });

function vlinegriddata() {
 var data = new Array();

 // line variables
 var vlineX1 = 0,
   vlineY1 = 0,
   vlineX2 = 50,
   vlineY2 = 0,
  click = 0;

 var lineLength = width;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension + 1; column++) {
   vlineClass = "vline" + vlineX1.toString() + vlineY1.toString() + vlineX2.toString() + vlineY2.toString();
   data.push({
    x1: vlineX1,
    y1: vlineY1,
    x2: vlineX2,
    y2: vlineY2,
    class: vlineClass,
    click: click
   });

        // increment the x position for the next line
        vlineY1 += lineLength;
        vlineY2 += lineLength;
  }

  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  vlineY1 = 0;
  vlineY2 = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  vlineX1 += lineLength;
  vlineX2 += lineLength;
 }
 return data;
}

var vlinegriddata = vlinegriddata();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(vlinegriddata);

var vline = grid.selectAll(".vline")
 .data(vlinegriddata)
 .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })
 .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
 .attr("click", function(d) { return d.click; })
 .style("stroke", "white")
 .style("stroke-width", "4")
 .style("cursor", "pointer")
 .on("click", function(){var nextColor = this.style.stroke == "white" ? "red" : "white";
            d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
 });
 // .on('click', function(d) {
    //    d.click ++;
    //    if ((d.click)%2 == 0 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#fff"); }
 //    if ((d.click)%2 == 1 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","red"); }
    // });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## line add selected.each()

```
hline
    .each(function(d){
        d.switch = 0;
    })
vline
    .each(function(d){
        d.switch = 0;
    })
```

## line change .on("click")

```
hline
    .on("click",function(d){
        var Color = ["white","red"];
        //switch ===> 0 or 1 
        d.switch = d.switch ^ 1;
        //color ===> "white" or "red"
        var nextColor = Color[d.switch];
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
    })

vline
    .on("click",function(d){
        var Color = ["white","red"];
        //switch ===> 0 or 1 
        d.switch = d.switch ^ 1;
        //color ===> "white" or "red"
        var nextColor = Color[d.switch];
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
    })
```

## rect change:

```
rect
.on("click", function(d){
    var Color = ["white" , "red"];
    d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
    d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
    d3.select(".hline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
    d3.select(".hline" + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
    function Next_Color(d){
        var Color = ["white","red"];
        d.switch = d.switch ^ 1;
        var next_Color = Color[d.switch];
        return next_Color;
    }
});
```

## Example

```js
// grid basic variables
var dimension = 10,
 width = 50,
 height = 50;

function gridData() {
 var data = new Array();

 // rectangle variables
 var rectXpos = 0,
   rectYpos = 0,
   rectWidth = width,
   rectHeight = height;
  click = 0;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension; column++) {
   // rectClass = "rect" + rectXpos.toString() + rectYpos.toString();
   data.push({
    x: rectXpos,
    y: rectYpos,
    width: rectWidth,
    height: rectHeight,
    // class: rectClass,
    click: click
   });

   // increment the x position. I.e. move it over by 50 (width variable)
   rectXpos += rectWidth;
  }
  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  rectXpos = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  rectYpos += rectHeight;
 }
 return data;
}

var gridData = gridData();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(gridData);

var grid = d3.select("#grid")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width*dimension)
 .attr("height",height*dimension);

var rect = grid.selectAll(".square")
 .data(gridData)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("class","rect")
 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
 .style("fill", "#f2f2f2")
 .style("stroke", "#fff")
 .on("click", function(d){
  var Color = ["white" , "red"];
  d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
  d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
  d3.select(".hline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);
  d3.select(".hline" + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke", Next_Color);


        function Next_Color(d){
            var Color = ["white","red"];
            d.switch = d.switch ^ 1;
            var next_Color = Color[d.switch];
            return next_Color;
        }
 });

function hlinegriddata() {
 var data = new Array();

 // line variables
 var hlineX1 = 0,
   hlineY1 = 0,
   hlineX2 = 0,
   hlineY2 = 50,
  click = 0;

 var lineLength = width;

 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension + 1; column++) {
   hlineClass = "hline" + hlineX1.toString() + hlineY1.toString() + hlineX2.toString() + hlineY2.toString();
   data.push({
    x1: hlineX1,
    y1: hlineY1,
    x2: hlineX2,
    y2: hlineY2,
    class: hlineClass,
    click: click
   });

        // increment the x position for the next line
        hlineX1 += lineLength;
        hlineX2 += lineLength;
  }

  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  hlineX1 = 0;
  hlineX2 = 0;

  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  hlineY1 += lineLength;
  hlineY2 += lineLength;
 }
 return data;
}

var hlinegriddata = hlinegriddata();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(hlinegriddata);

var hline = grid.selectAll(".hline")
 .data(hlinegriddata)
 .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })
 .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
 .style("stroke", "white")
 .style("stroke-width", "4")
 .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .each(function(d){
        d.switch = 0;
    })
 .on("click", function(d){
        var Color = ["white","red"];
        d.switch = d.switch ^ 1;
        var nextColor = Color[d.switch];
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
 });
 // .on('click', function(d) {
 //  d.click ++;
    //    if ((d.click)%2 == 0 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#fff"); }
 //    if ((d.click)%2 == 1 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","red"); }
    // });

function vlinegriddata() {
 var data = new Array();

 // line variables
 var vlineX1 = 0,
   vlineY1 = 0,
   vlineX2 = 50,
   vlineY2 = 0,
  click = 0;

 var lineLength = width;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension + 1; column++) {
   vlineClass = "vline" + vlineX1.toString() + vlineY1.toString() + vlineX2.toString() + vlineY2.toString();
   data.push({
    x1: vlineX1,
    y1: vlineY1,
    x2: vlineX2,
    y2: vlineY2,
    class: vlineClass,
    click: click
   });

        // increment the x position for the next line
        vlineY1 += lineLength;
        vlineY2 += lineLength;
  }

  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  vlineY1 = 0;
  vlineY2 = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  vlineX1 += lineLength;
  vlineX2 += lineLength;
 }
 return data;
}

var vlinegriddata = vlinegriddata();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(vlinegriddata);

var vline = grid.selectAll(".vline")
 .data(vlinegriddata)
 .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })
 .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
 .attr("click", function(d) { return d.click; })
 .style("stroke", "white")
 .style("stroke-width", "4")
 .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .each(function(d){
        d.switch = 0;
    })
 .on("click", function(d){
        var Color = ["white","red"];
        d.switch = d.switch ^ 1;
        var nextColor = Color[d.switch];
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
        //var nextColor = this.style.stroke == "white" ? "red" : "white";
        //d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);
 });
 // .on('click', function(d) {
    //    d.click ++;
    //    if ((d.click)%2 == 0 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#fff"); }
 //    if ((d.click)%2 == 1 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","red"); }
    // });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect :)

Comment: @khlan  I think this idea is great！I want to know where I can use it？

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Based on this article (https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.021029) i make a demonstration for the basic transformations in this concept. So basicly i need this because qubits.